# Refrigerator is unplugged a couple days for cleaning, once plugged back in will not start

Tags: refrigerator

Amana - brand, perfectly functioning refrigerator,  was unplugged in preparation for cleaning and including in sale of house.

It was unplugged only 2-3 days, but now when it’s plugged back in it won’t start up.

Any idea why this would happen?  Is it destined for the junk yard?

Answer (score 1):

If the refrigerator was unplugged during its defrost cycle, it may take some time to complete the cycle before kicking the compressor back on. Leave it plugged in for a few hours.

As mentioned in another answer, first check to make sure the outlet has power. Other than that, give it some time and see if it comes to life.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the headslappers (was it **also turned off at its internal thermostat**, and you forgot to turn that to cold when plugging it back in?) it does sound like it inconveniently chose right about now as a time to expire. Do **verify that the outlet itself has power**, under this heading.

I would negotiate with the buyers regarding the knocking off the value of a fridge evidently near the end of its life as an adjustment in closing, allowing them to select their own replacement fridge, unless you have some local requirement to sell the house with a functioning fridge.

Comment: Some fridges have heaters on the compressor that need to be powered for 4 hours before the compressor will start, it is a rare feature for protecting the compressor from icing as any moisture ends up in the compressor oil and if not heated prior to start up some damage to the compressor can be expected but this is usually on large built in units I don't think I have seen it on standard units may be worth it to leave it plugged in to see if it has this protection.

Comment: As @Ecnerwal states, check the outlet: GFCI's may need to be reset.